# Ajuda para gravar dois valores em $_SESSION usando um único form radio

Tags: php

Tenho este código abaixo funcionando perfeito para gravar no BD:

```
            <?php
        include '../conexao.php';

        $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
        $servico = $_POST['servico'];
        $servico_status = $_POST['servico_status'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        // checar se foi postado algo:
        if (isset($_POST['servico_status'])) { // só entra aqui, se gale_status tiver sido postado
            $link = null;
            $status = 'Não';
            // se a pessoa marcar a opção sim:
            if ($_POST['servico_status'] == 1) {
                $status = 'Sim';
                $link = '<li><a href="'.$res['dominio'].'serv_index.php" class="nav1">'.$res['bot_serv'].'</a></li><li class="divider"></li>';
            }
            // acho que tá faltando definir uma id em seu update.
            $update = mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET servico = '$link', servico_status = '$status'");
            if ($update == '') {
                echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Erro ao Habilitar Link ".$res['bot_serv']."!');</script>";
            } else {
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
                          <script language='javascript'>window.alert('Link ".$res['bot_serv']." Habilitado com sucesso!');</script>";
            }
        }

        //  só use: enctype="multipart/form-data" quando o formulário fizer upload de algum arquivo.
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link <?php echo $res['bot_serv'];?>?</label><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='servico_status' value='1' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type="radio" name="servico_status" value='0'><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Porém estou tentando criar um simulador e preciso adaptar esse código acima, para que ele grave em duas $_SESSION diferentes, na $_SESSION['hab_prod']['status_prod'] e na $_SESSION['hab_prod']['link_prod'].

Código Editado:

Alterei o código e só consegui atingir o meu objetivo que é gravar o na $_SESSION['hab_prod'] o $status_prod Habilitado (Sim ou Não) e o $link_prod (Endereço do Botão), incluindo mais um Radio, e no PHP separando o código individualmente.

Na Página terei que estar selecionando os dois radio para que funcione.

Pergunto aos amigos se não tem uma outra forma onde poderei selecionar um único radio para gravar as duas opções de value's.

```
  <?php
  @session_start(); // Inicia a session.

    //pega o valor do botao
    $botao=$_POST['atualizar'];
    //verifica se o botao foi clicado
    if($botao=="Atualizar"){
       $status_prod = $_POST['status_prod'];       
    if(isset($status_prod)) {
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']["status_prod"] = $status_prod;
    }}
    //pega o valor do botao
    $botao=$_POST['atualizar'];
    //verifica se o botao foi clicado
    if($botao=="Atualizar"){
       $link_prod = $_POST['link_prod'];
    if(isset($status_prod)) {
        $_SESSION['hab_prod']["link_prod"] = $link_prod;

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= menu_halitar_link.php'>
    <script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
    </script>";
    }}
    ?>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link <?php echo $bot_prod ?>?</label><br><br>
            <input style="margin-left:-66px;" type='radio' name='link_prod'
            value='<li><a href="<?php echo $end ?>prod_index.php" class="nav1"><?php echo $bot_prod ?></a></li><li class="divider"></li>'
            checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type="radio" name="link_prod" value=''><label>Não</label><br />
            <input type='radio' name='status_prod' value='Sim' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type="radio" name="status_prod" value='Não'><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" name="atualizar" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz ou mesmo me mostrar como devo fazer, ficarei agradecido.

No aguardo de boas dicas, abraços à todos.

Comment: Tá mas exatamente o que não está funcionando?

Comment: Não estará a faltar `session_start();`? antes do primeiro `if`?

Comment: Olá Igor, não esta gravando os value's nas  $_SESSION. E Miguel realmente eu não postei a session_start() aqui no post, por esquecimento, pois eu estou usando no servidor um include session.php com todas as $_SESSION criadas.

Comment: Inseri o session_start(), e fiz umas alterações para botar para funcionar de forma engatilhada, ou seja não sendo do jeito que gostaria, pois tive que inserir mais um radio para poder gravar os dois value o referente ao link e outro referente ao status. Mas gostaria que fosse com um único  radio para gravar os dois value. Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz de como poderei executar tal tarefa, ficarei agradecido. Obrigado e abraços a todos.